# Reroute web traffic. Act as gateway

Tags: redirect, routes, gateway

In hotels WiFi is unprotected and everyone can connect. But no matter the requested url you are redirected to their "Give a password" page.

I am interested in making something similar but I'm kinda lost. I don't know where to start.

What is the minimum hardware required for such thing, do I have to buy a special router that does this or I can simply get a computer with Apache or IIS and manage traffic from there?

**edit:**

Since second scenario is more likely to be the answer, I am looking for some info on where to start.

Comment: you probably need to build a captive portal. Here is where to start : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal